# Should I catch errors in a function which calls just a function which already uses try and catch in its body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

I to have write a function that checks if a file is valid (exists & granted correct permissions), and other one that returns a valid filepath. These functions call the check file function which uses try catch.

Should my function validFilePath catch errors also?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to use `try/catch` in all circumstances.

If there is no code path that causes the function you're calling to throw, then you don't need to surround it with a `try/catch`.  It is your responsibility as a programmer to know what the functions you call can do in terms of errors and to code to that.  Do they return an error?  Do they return `null`?  Do they throw an exception?  If they do not throw an exception because they already catch any possible exception, then there is no reason for the caller to surround the function call with a `try/catch`.

You do need to code for all possible return values, including error conditions.

Comment: @Josue Quinteros: If this solved your question, please mark the answer as accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. In which "scope" do you recommend hand errors?

Comment: @JosueQuinteros - It depends upon what you're code is doing so we'd have to see your actual code in order to make a more specific recommendation.